# How to extract slick entities from play framework dao singleton

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I've been creating a new project using Play framework, Slick and Postgresql and I don't understand how can I extract entities from DAO. Most tutorials show examples where entity (class extending table) is a class within dao singleton.

I've done actually the same:

```
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfigProvider}
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

@Singleton
class CardDao @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
                       (implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import dbConfig.profile.api._

  val Cards = TableQuery[CardsTable]

  private[dao] class CardsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Card](tag, "card") {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name", O.Unique)
    def value = column[BigDecimal]("value")
    def currencyId = column[Int]("currency_id")
    def created = column[DateTime]("created")
    def active = column[Boolean]("active")

    override def * = (id, name, value, currencyId, created) <> (Card.tupled, Card.unapply)
  }

  def all(): Future[Seq[Card]] = db.run(Cards.result)
}
```

That's ok. I don't mind having an entity here but when I create another DAO I cannot access my TableQuery (joining tables or creating foreign keys) as it's just a field in singleton.

I was trying to extract CardsTable to separate class with companion object containing TableQuery but it turns out that column method, O, foreignKey come somewhere from HasDatabaseConfigProvider trait (importing dbConfig.profile.api._) so I'm not sure but I guess I have to pass dbConfig implicitly to the class.

How would you do that ? It's just the beginning of the project so really don't want to make some rookie mistakes at this point.

Comment: Try creating `trait Tables { this: HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] => ... }` and put your common tables in there and mix it in into all daos that need them.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Łukasz I've found a way how to do this:

```
trait Tables {
  this: HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] => {}

  import dbConfig.profile.api._

  val Cards = TableQuery[CardsTable]
  val FaceValues = TableQuery[FaceValuesTable]
  val Currencies = TableQuery[CurrenciesTable]
  val Cryptocurrencies = TableQuery[CryptocurrenciesTable]
  val Wallets = TableQuery[WalletsTable]
  val Transactions = TableQuery[TransactionsTable]

  class CryptocurrenciesTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Cryptocurrency](tag, "cryptocurrency") with ActiveAndCreated[Cryptocurrency] {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name", O.Unique)
    def cryptocurrencyCode = column[String]("cryptocurrency_code", O.Unique)
    def blockchainExplorerUrl = column[String]("blockchain_explorer_url")
    def iconSvg = column[String]("icon_svg")

    override def * = (id, name, cryptocurrencyCode, blockchainExplorerUrl, iconSvg, created) <>
      (Cryptocurrency.tupled, Cryptocurrency.unapply)
  }

  class FaceValuesTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[FaceValue](tag, "face_value") with ActiveAndCreated[FaceValue] {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def value = column[BigDecimal]("value")
    def currencyId = column[Int]("currency_id")
    def cardId = column[Int]("card_id")

    def card = foreignKey("card_fk", cardId, Cards)(_.id)
    def currency = foreignKey("currency_fk", currencyId, Currencies)(_.id)

    override def * = (id, value, currencyId, cardId) <> (FaceValue.tupled, FaceValue.unapply)
  }

...
}
```

Simple Dao trait:

```
trait Dao extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] with Tables
```

And now all DAOs are very simple:

```
@Singleton
class WalletDao @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
                         (implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends Dao {
  import dbConfig.profile.api._

  def find(walletAddress: WalletAddress): Future[Option[Wallet]] = {
    val query = for {
      wallet         <- Wallets
      cryptocurrency <- Cryptocurrencies if cryptocurrency.id === wallet.id &&
        cryptocurrency.cryptocurrencyCode === walletAddress.cryptocurrency
    } yield wallet
    db.run(query.result.headOption)
  }

  def find(walletId: Int): Future[Option[Wallet]] = db.run(Wallets.filter(_.id === walletId).result.headOption)

  def save(wallet: Wallet): Future[Int] = db.run(Wallets += wallet)
}
```